# Why does FB ignore the picture, name, and caption parameter when posting a link on a user's stream?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have my app posting a link to the user's wall if they have given it permissions, but it ignores the picture, name, and caption values I pass along with it.

```
HTTParty.post("https://graph.facebook.com/#{@sponsorship.fbid}/links", :query => {:access_token => URI.escape(@access_token), :link => URI.escape(request.env['HTTP_HOST']), :picture => URI.escape("#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}/images/fb_post/after_donation.jpg"), :name => URI.encode("Click here"), :caption => URI.encode("This is the caption")})
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should know that posting to the users wall automatically without warning or a way for the user to skip posting it after they have granted permissions is kind of bad and breaks Facebook policy

Answer (score 1):

Think you might need to be using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/#{@sponsorship.fbid}/feed
```

instead of

```
https://graph.facebook.com/#{@sponsorship.fbid}/links
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably taking those values from the open graph meta tags on the link target rather than the ones you provide at post time. Not sure if that's supposed to be happening but you should check if your link has the correct tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ is the docs and https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug will show you what markup is detected on your page